# How do I open Chromium in incognito mode by default?

Tags: chromium

I would like to be able to open Chromium in incognito mode automatically. I'm new to Linux and I love it so far but I haven't yet found a way to do this. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This should work for all flavours of Ubuntu, no?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assume you mean the Chromium Web Browser.

You have to change one line in the `chromium-browser.desktop` file. The best is to do that locally:

1. Copy the file from `/usr/share/applications` to `/home/yourname/.local/share/applications`
2. Open the file with gedit (open gedit and drag the local desktop file on to the gedit window)
3. Find the *first line* in the file that begins with `Exec=`
4. Replace the line by `Exec=chromium-browser --incognito`

a few remarks:

- The folder `/home/yourname/.local/share/applications` is a hidden folder by default. To make it visibe: go to your home folder, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>, the `.local` folder will appear.
- You can copy the `chromium-browser.desktop` file to your local folder with the command: `cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`
- You might have to log out and back in before the changes to take effect.

Comment: Yep, logging out/in did the trick. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I downvoted this too, more complex and not as good as [this older answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/414808/29097). This method doesn't open it by default, it makes a shortcut that opens it specifically.

Comment: Is there a proper icon for [Chrome Incognito](https://i.imgur.com/vbQBUcC.png)?

Comment: Hi @orschiro I found this: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/incognito-mode-shortcut/ or more precisely this: https://cdn1.tekrevue.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/chrome-incognito.ico

Comment: Thanks, @JacobVlijm. So, the Ubuntu Google Chrome package [doesn't ship a default one](http://i.imgur.com/SPqiVti.png)?

Comment: @orschiro Not that I know of. That would also require automatic replacement of the icon, which Chrome doesn't as far as I know.

Comment: works also for 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps,

1. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser` and select `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`. This will make Chromium your system's default browser.
2. Run `sudo -e /etc/chromium-browser/default` (edit as root), and change the line that reads `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""` to `CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--incognito"`.

That's it. Changes are instantaneous.

Also, if you ever want to open chrome without incognito mode, just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> in incognito mode.

See also,

- [*Where can I configure Chromium's default command line arguments?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/1095503/29097)

Comment: The question asks for `incognito` for both Chromium and Google Chrome—where in the world is the `default` file for Chrome?

Comment: @Oxwivi your distro doesn't control or bundle Google Chrome. The version of Google Chrome that they do bundle, they call Chromium. Google forces them to rename the browser because they technically publish their own patches, like the one that has the *default file*. It also doesn't make sense to have "a default" for more than one browser because the WM will only launch only one when you click a link.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it using alacarte (main menu).
Install alacarte (aka main menu) from the Ubuntu Software Center if you don't already have it. Launch it.

On the left hand side, under **Menus**, make sure **Applications** is expanded. Look for **Internet**. Single click it. Now look for **Chrome** under **Items**. Single click it. Look for **Properties** on the right hand side. Single click it. A little window appears. (I've dragged it to the right for clarity.) Look for **Command**. For me, I see `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U`.

[image: using alacarte]

Carefully change that to:
`/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --incognito %U`

Click **Close** on the little window and then click **Close** on the Main Menu window. You need to **log out** and **log in** to make the change register.

You're done.

(I just did it so I know it works.)

Answer (score 1):

1. You need create a `Chrome incognito.desktop` file like with the following contents:

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Chrome incognito
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --incognito
   Terminal=false
   Icon=google-chrome
   Type=Application
   Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
   MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
   ```
2. Save this file, open Nautilus with root permission (run `gksu nautilus`).
3. Browse to `/usr/share/applications` and paste the file here.
4. Now you can drag this icon to your launcher.
5. Click on launcher icon, Chrome will start in incognito mode.

Comment: Can't one just use ala carte (main menu) to do this via a GUI?

Answer (score -1):

The solution which worked for me:

1. open an incognito window
2. lock it to luncher
3. remove the other chrome from luncher
4. whenever you click this icon in luncher an incognito window of chrome will be opened.