# Chromium Signal App crashing in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, chromium, signal, chrome-extension

When I try to launch Signal through the launcher on Linux with the following

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk
```

It crashes, nothing happens. This is what the Desktop Application link calls. But when I click [`LAUNCH APP`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signal-private-messenger/bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) in the web store, it works.

Any idea of how the web store's `LAUNCH APP` link works or what can be responsible. I don't see any errors either way in the developer's console.

Comment: I know it is frustrating  but hard to give you advice without an error message. As the application works my guess is a problem with one of the options you have, either a problem with the Default directory or app-id. Can you just run `chromium-browser` without options and then test one a t a time.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I found the issue, and self-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--incognito"
```

I had Chromium set to open up in incognito mode in `/etc/chromium-browser/default` as [per these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/414808/29097). That stops the application from attaching to the current session. It produces this in STDERR..

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=bikioccmkafdpakkkcpdbppfkghcmihk
Using PPAPI flash.
--incognito --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=

Created new window in existing browser session.
```

But no further errors. No window is created in my existing browser session.

*[Bug filed in Github issue tracker here](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Desktop/issues/1142)*