# Where can I configure Chromium's default command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, configuration, chromium

Where can I store default [command line arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to chromium?

Like if I want to set the `password-store`, `incognito`, or the proxy options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store those arguments in `/etc/chromium-browser/default`

```
sudo -e /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

Then set it appropriately

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--incognito --password-store=gnome"
```